# How do we fetch inner value from value in Hashmap in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, hashmap

I have got a Hashmap entry in Eclipse as below:

[Link to the picture of the hashmap output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pSIh.png)

I'm unable to fetch the value using the key = "value".
Error that I'm receiving is as:
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Double cannot be cast to class java.util.Map (java.lang.Double and java.util.Map are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Code with which I'm trying to fetch is as below:

Map<Object, Double> billed_amount_value = new HashMap<Object, Double>();

billed_amount_value = (Map<Object, Double>) billed_amount.get("value");

I'm unable to fetch the value using the key = "value". Can someone please help me to get the right code?

Answer (score 0):

Your `hashmap` key type is **Object** while the value for that key is **Double**. Once you use

```
billed_amount.get("value")
```

The returned value is **Double** (it returns the value of the key = "value").
After that you try to cast the return value (Double type) into Map type.

What are you trying to do? Get back the value of which his key equals "value"?